# How can I automatically close the InAppBrowser after post has been shared?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus

I am fairly new to Ionic and Cordova and I am using Cordova to create an application.

I've written code to open an InAppBrowser window in order to share a link via Google+.

My code works fine however, once the user has shared the link they are redirected in the InAppBrowser to their Google+ page. How would I go about closing the InAppBrowser window after the user has successfully shared their post?

```
    $scope.googleShare = function(url){
      var siteToShare = "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=<?php echo rawurlencode("+url+")";     
      var options = "location=no,toolbar=yes,toolbarposition=top"
      var ref = window.open(siteToShare, '_blank', options);
      ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event){
          if(event.url.match("mobile/close")){
              ref.close();
          }
      })
      console.log(siteToShare);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically close the `InAppBrowser` by listening for the `loadstart` event, which is fired whenever the browser starts loading a new page. If you use `loadstop`, the user will see that the browser goes to a different page.

The following code is an example as to how you can close the browser using the `loadstart` event. All you have to do is replace `"part of URL here"` with whatever works for you.

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
  if(event.url.indexOf("part of URL here") > -1) {
    ref.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: what about the page when it added cookie (added by server side php code ) then i want to close it

Comment: If that happens on a specific URL, you can listen for that URL as I have mentioned above, but use the `loadstop` event instead of `loadstart`.